# React redux prop object property undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-redux, axios

I am new to React Redux. I am not sure what is wrong on my code. There is no error on the terminal but when I take a look on the browser there is a TypeError. ItemsProduct was on the props. I was wondering why it returns an error when I am trying to access the properties.

> productDescription.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";

import {
  fetchProductsRequests,
  fetchProductsSuccess,
  fetchProductError,
} from "../../actions/productActions";

class ProductDescription extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProducts();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6 mb-10">
          <div className="col-start-2 col-end-4">
            <h4>{this.props.itemsProduct[0].name}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    itemsProduct: state.rootProduct.products.filter(
      (prod) => prod.id == ownProps.match.params.id
    ),
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchProducts: () => {
      dispatch(fetchProductsRequests());
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/js/products.json")
        .then((response) => {
          dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(response.data));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          dispatch(fetchProductError(error.message));
        });
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductDescription);
```

> productActions.js

```
export const FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUESTS = "FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUESTS";
export const FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS = "FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS";
export const FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR = "FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR";

export const fetchProductsRequests = () => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUESTS,
  };
};

export const fetchProductsSuccess = (product) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
    payload: product,
  };
};

export const fetchProductError = (error) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR,
    payload: error,
  };
};
```

> productReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  loading: true,
  products: [],
  error: "",
};

const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUESTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };

    case "FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS":
      return {
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload,
        error: "",
      };

    case "FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR":
      return {
        loading: false,
        products: [],
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default productReducer;
```

> Root Reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import productReducer from "./productReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  rootProduct: productReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: In the reducer, you aren't actually setting any state for products

Comment: Your Axios Get request getting data, right? You can check on network tab on the browser's developer screen(f12).

Comment: Yes. I was able to see the data on the props but when I try to access it on the render method like this this.props.itemsProduct[0].name it returns a TypeError of undefined property.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a quick check if there is data coming from your axios by doing this (it will prevent any undefined or null values)

`dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(response.data || 'no data'));`

Also you should return your state in the reducer as follows:

```
case "FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload,
        error: "",
      };

    case "FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        products: [],
        error: action.payload,
      };
```

Your

```
itemsProduct: state.rootProduct.products.filter(
      (prod) => prod.id == ownProps.match.params.id
    ),
```

may return an empty array meaning you will not be able to retrieve that object in your view

```
<h4>{this.props.itemsProduct[0].name}</h4>
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I have tried to applied it but output is still the same. I was wondering why I cant do codes like this this.props.itemsProduct[0].name since it will only return one object because I filtered it on the mapstatetoprops. But when I map it, it actually works. Is that the best method that I can do ?

Comment: @bbarriatos can you show the content of ```state.rootProduct.products```

Comment: I figured it out.Though I am not sure if this is the best practice. I noticed that the reason why I can't access the properties of the props is because render() method comes first before the componentDidMount(). What I did is I changed componentDidMount() to componentWillMount()